# PHP: Class 'Thread' not found

Tags: php, multithreading, apache

I know guys, this question has been answered but belive me before I ask it I followed step by step these two questions but still having the same error.
[pthread not working in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634423/pthread-not-working-in-php)
[PHP pthreads: Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22901578/php-pthreads-fatal-error-class-thread-not-found)

I have added this line `extension=php_pthreads.dll` to the php.ini file located in the apache directory `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini`.
Also I have the file `pthreadVC2.dll` under `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin`, and the file `php_pthreads.dll` under `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext`.
After that I restarted the wamp server and checked the `php_pthreads` extension and it's activated.
[image]
I did everything as described but still facing this error.
**This is my class that extends from `Thread`:**

```
class MyThread extends \Thread
{

    public function run()
    {
        echo 'This is a thread';
    }
}
```

And this is how I called it:

```
$myThread = new MyThread();
$myThread->start();
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @GiorgioSintichakis 5.5.12

Comment: Are you by chance using an autoloader or manually including the class?

Comment: @Gsinti I'm using composer's autoloader

Answer (score 0):

You should use [pthreads 2.0.10](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/) for PHP version 5.5.12. You should also try copying pthreadVC2.dll and php_pthreads.dll at your `c:/windows/system32` directory.